# On server link is not working properly

Tags: php, linux

I have a search link in my project,by clicking the user will redirect to another page and accoroding to the get value,the data will displayed.Everything is working fine in my localhost.But when I put my file into server its says page not found.I don't know what is happening.

The link in my loclhost:-

```
http://localhost/sampleproject?pickuplocation=Adelaide&returnlocation=Melbourne&vehicle=Campervan (2 berth)
```

in url its show like this :-

```
http://localhost/sampleproject?pickuplocation=Adelaide&returnlocation=Melbourne&vehicle=Campervan+%282+berth%29
```

Its works fine.

On server link is :-

```
http://www.example.com/?pickuplocation=Adelaide&returnlocation=Melbourne&vehicle=Campervan (2 berth)
```

in url its show like this(server) :-

```
http://www.example.com/?pickuplocation=Adelaide&returnlocation=Melbourne&vehicle=Campervan+%282+berth%29
```

this link on server throws an error that `PAGE NOT FOUND`.
I don't know what is happening.Please help me on this ,thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you perfectly sure it's not `example.com/sampleproject`?

Comment: yes @SiGanteng .The link which i provide here is correct

Comment: I think you should check your .htaccess file .

Comment: try with [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the problem will be with your .htaccess file try to move around it.